# dom tree vs. xslt processor tree - what is the difference?

Tags: dom, xslt

Since DOM is a tree representation of XML and xslt processors use tree structures as their input, I was wondering what is the difference between the DOM and a tree structure of an xslt processor? and how can a xslt processor such as Saxon be implemented on SAX? Does that mean  that it generates the input tree structure from the events the SAX reports? Isnt that a little cumbersome? Why use something that doesnt already provide a tree structure?

Comment: In the case of Saxon it is _able_ to process a W3C DOM tree but if you give it the raw bytes then it can build its own (non-DOM) tree structure in its own internal object model which it can handle far more efficiently than a W3C DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since DOM is a tree representation of XML

While you can use DOM with XML, DOM is most often a tree representation of HTML.

> and xslt processors use tree structures as their input,

When I use `saxon` at the command line I give it a file. It is a sequence of bytes, not a tree. Something has to transform this sequence into a tree.

> I was wondering what is the difference between the DOM and a tree structure of an xslt processor?

Listing all the differences would be too long but some salient ones:

- DOM trees are supposed to conform to a set of standards. They have a public interface. The trees used by XSLT processors do not have to conform to any standard. An XSLT processor could very well create its own tree, which is designed to be used only for its own purposes.
- DOM trees are usually structurally mutable. Trees used for XSLT processing could be structurally mutable but are usually used immutably. (By "structurally mutable" I'm talking about adding, removing, moving elements around. There's no facility in XSLT to modify the input as it is processed.)
- DOM trees support things that don't make sense in XSLT processing. For instance, event handlers.

> and how can a xslt processor such as Saxon be implemented on SAX? Does that mean that it generates the input tree structure from the events the SAX reports? Isnt that a little cumbersome? Why use something that doesnt already provide a tree structure?

Yes, an XSLT processor would use SAX's events to generate a tree for internal processing. (And it seems this is what Saxon does.) There are good reasons one might use SAX to construct a custom tree rather than, say, use a library that constructs a DOM tree. Earlier I said that XSLT processors usually use their tree as structurally immutable. This can allow for optimizations that a DOM implementation might not be able to perform. Here's an example. If your tree is structurally immutable, you can compute the list of child *elements* of a node once and for all. It cannot ever change once it is computed. However, in a DOM tree, the list of child *elements* of a node *can* change because the tree is mutable. So you have to have provisions to handle changes. Custom trees also do not have to support things that don't make sense for XSLT processing, like events. These kinds of optimizations may lead to an application that takes less memory and runs faster.

Comment: Wow, thanx for that answer!! So, would it be fair to say that it actually makes more sense NOT to implement an xslt processor with a DOM parser?

Comment: It depends on goals. If I were starting from zero and the only thing at hand is something that gives me a DOM tree and I'm aiming at getting an xslt processor ready to use quickly, I'd work with a DOM tree. If I'm after optimizing the xslt processor at all costs, even if it means that it will be ready later, then I'd skip the DOM tree and work with something optimized for the task of xslt processing. These are two extremes. It is also possible take the middle of the road and work with a DOM tree which is converted to an optimized tree, the benefits would be a mix of the two extremes.